# How to update or upgrade from glib 2.17 version to glib 2.4(over) version on Amazon Linux 1?

Tags: update, upgrade, glib

How to update or upgrade from glib 2.17 version to glib 2.4(over) version on Amazon Linux 1?

Or downgrade to 2.12 is fine.

Comment: What does "(over)" mean here?

Comment: more than ver.2.4

Comment: ver.2.4 -> ver.2.40

Comment: 2.4? That's extremely old. Nobody would be using that any more. And that would be a significant downgrade from 2.17. Did you mean 2.40? Also you probably should already be on Amazon Linux 2, or better yet, a completely different distribution.

Comment: Yes. It is version 2.40. Does that mean you can install glib 2.40 on Amazon Linux 2?

Comment: Amazon Linux 2 already has glib 2.56.